# Android appBarLayout behavior nestedScroll disable wrong

Tags: android

Problem :
I  have a xml as follow:

In the android support design 23.1.1

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/myMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/myappBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="450dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/quila2"
                    android:tint="#11000000"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollmyMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:contentPadding="16dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/lorem"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you want to disable the nestedscroll as follow:

```
mCoordinatorLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
mAppBarLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

You will find that if you touch and move  the appBar the nestScrollView can aslo be moved , that means the nestedScroll can not be disabled.

The reason I found is in the support design libraray 23.1.1 
AppBarLayout's Behavior  extends HeaderBehavior   23.1.1
AppBarLayout's  Behavior  extends ViewOffsetBehavior  22.2.1

the HeaderBehavior has  ovverride

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent ev) {
   scroll
};
```

So in another  ways ,  destroyed this mechanism.

If you want to disable all nestedScroll in the design support 23.1.1

you should extend the appBar's Behavior

I think it maybe a bug for support 23.1.1

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to confirm If it is the AppBarLayout's bug in  23.1.1